# What is the relationship between the ratio $y_{i}/x_{i}$ and the residuals of a linear regression $y_{i}$~$x_{i}$?

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, ratio

My background in statistical mathematics is poor. I don't know why $y_{i}/x_{i}$ and the residuals of the linear regression $y_{i}$~$x_{i}$ are always linearly related (whether X and Y are related or not).  Can someone explain what is going on there (mathematically and intuitively)?

This question is motivated by wanting to use a ratio in a regression (e.g., $y_{i}$~ $x_{i}/z_{i}$), and not quite understanding how this is different from $y_{i}$~ (residuals of $x_{i}$~$z_{i}$), and knowing that one shouldn't use residuals in a regression, rather just regress $y_{i}$ ~ $x_{i}$ + $z_{i}$).

Example in R, with no relationship:

```
x= rnorm(20,100,10)
y= rnorm(20,100,10)
plot(resid(lm(y~x)), y/x)
```

or with relationship:

```
x= rnorm(20,100,10)
y= x+rnorm(20,0,10)
plot(resid(lm(y~x)), y/x)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that in a linear model, you are assuming that $Y$ is simply a linear combination of the predictors and an error term, $Y = \beta X + \epsilon$. If the linear model produced an unbiased estimate of the $\beta$s, residuals from `lm` is just the $\epsilon$ vector. Also, $y/x = (\beta x + \epsilon)/x = \beta  + \epsilon/x$.

Thus, when you run

```
plot(resid(lm(y~x)), y/x)
```

you are in fact plotting $\epsilon$ against $\beta + \epsilon / x$. If your $\epsilon$ is not much smaller than $\sigma(X)$, you should be able to clearly see a linear relationship. Compare:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
x = rnorm(20,100,10)
e_small = rnorm(20,0,10)
e_large = rnorm(20,0,10)
y_small = x+e_small
y_large = x+e_large
plot(resid(lm(y_small~x)), y_small/x)
plot(resid(lm(y_large~x)), y_large/x)
```

[image]

As for the part about regressing `y ~ residuals(x~z)`: it is perfectly legitimate, and equivalent to `y ~ x + z`, if the predictors are orthogonal. Regressing each predictor successively, like `y ~ residuals(x[n-1] ~ residuals(x[n-2] ~ ... residuals(x[2] ~ x[1]) ... ))`, is also known as a [Gram-Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process). The main problem with it is that once the algorithm reaches a predictor that is collinear with the already included ones, the residuals become small and subject to rounding errors, thus producing numerically unstable $\beta$ estimates.

Comment: The second part doesn't seem to check out.  y~ resid(lm(x~z)) is not equivalent to y~x+z.  y~x/z is close but not the same to y~ resid(lm(x~z)), but neither is similar to y~x+z.  I'm still at a loss for what the reason (mathematical and intuitive) is for why resid(lm(y~lm(resid(x~z))) is similar but different from resid(lm(y~x/z)), and what that means for regression analysis.

Comment: Here's the code I used:                                                                        vars= mvrnorm(n=20, mu=c(0,0), Sigma=diag(1,2), empirical=TRUE);
x=vars[,1];
z=vars[,2];
cor(x,z);
y= x + z + rnorm(20,0,.5);
x.z= x/z;
res1= resid(lm(y~x/z));
res2= resid(lm(y~resid(lm(x~z))));
res3= resid(lm(y~x+z));
plot(res1,res2)

Comment: @DaveM `res2` and `res3` appear different in the visual analysis because of low variance in the error term that you add to `y` - try increasing it to get bigger range, and you will see that they form a linear relationship. Though, Gram-Schmidt procedure gives correct _coefficient estimates_ (you can see by comparing the coefficients of `x` obtained both ways), but I'm not so sure if the standard errors are unchanged - there might be not much point looking into residuals then.

Comment: @DaveM regarding predictors of type $x/z$ - I do not see why that would have any bad effects on the regression. If your $z$ has very little variance, $x/z$ will be strongly collinear with $x$, and it will be difficult to distinguish their effects in a model `y ~ x + x/z` (resulting in high standard errors of the betas). The effect estimates for both $x$ and $x/z$ should be unbiased in any case.

Answer (score 1):

You have a simple linear regression model $y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i + \varepsilon_i$, so this gives:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\frac{y_i}{x_i} 
= \frac{\hat{y}_i + r_i}{x_i} 
&= \frac{\hat{\beta}_0 + \hat{\beta}_1 x_i + r_i}{x_i} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{\hat{\beta}_0}{x_i} + \hat{\beta}_1 + \frac{r_i}{x_i}. \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

This equation gives you the relationship between the ratio $y_i / x_i$ and the residuals $r_i$ from the specified linear model.  In the example in your post, you generate data that has no linear relationship, so the middle term of this equation (which estimates the slope of the relationship) is approximately zero.  You also have predictor values $x_i$ that don't vary much, so that makes the denominator underneath the residual value quite stable.  So in this case, it is unsurprising that you have a relationship that looks roughly linear.  That is not a general property of the relationship --- it is just something that has arisen from your particular parameter specification.

Taking a reproducible version of your example allows us to see the estimated coefficients in the fitted regression model, and this allows you to calculate the decomposition in the above equation, for each data point.  You can see from this that there is a roughly increasing relationship between the ratio values and the residuals.

```
#Generate data with no relationship
set.seed(1);
x <- rnorm(20, 100, 10);
y <- rnorm(20, 100, 10);

#Generate simple linear model
MODEL <- lm(y ~ x)

MODEL;

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
   121.0855      -0.2075  

#Create decomposition of ratio statistic
DECOMP <- data.frame(Term_1 = MODEL$coefficient[1]/x,
                     Term_2 = MODEL$coefficient[2]*rep(1, 20),
                     Term_3 = MODEL$residuals/x,
                     Ratio  = y/x,
                     Resid  = MODEL$residuals);

DECOMP
     Term_1     Term_2       Term_3     Ratio       Resid
1  1.291779 -0.2075476  0.080640467 1.1648716   7.5588714
2  1.189019 -0.2075476  0.077298443 1.0587700   7.8717978
3  1.321263 -0.2075476 -0.014396948 1.0993187  -1.3193898
4  1.044265 -0.2075476 -0.145863329 0.6908542 -16.9132626
5  1.172229 -0.2075476  0.063424420 1.0281057   6.5514304
6  1.319081 -0.2075476 -0.028267916 1.0832656  -2.5948623
7  1.154577 -0.2075476 -0.008362587 0.9386671  -0.8770203
8  1.127601 -0.2075476 -0.125772517 0.7942810 -13.5058612
9  1.144932 -0.2075476 -0.037039275 0.9003448  -3.9171927
10 1.248998 -0.2075476  0.033161481 1.0746115   3.2148768
11 1.051840 -0.2075476  0.142408444 0.9867004  16.3937484
12 1.165422 -0.2075476 -0.005288622 0.9525853  -0.5494796
13 1.291061 -0.2075476  0.024061111 1.1075742   2.2566337
14 1.555309 -0.2075476 -0.070200495 1.2775609  -5.4653193
15 1.088415 -0.2075476 -0.105767318 0.7751006 -11.7665411
16 1.216320 -0.2075476 -0.045945618 0.9628269  -4.5739168
17 1.212818 -0.2075476 -0.043141994 0.9621287  -4.3072146
18 1.106426 -0.2075476  0.009457953 0.9083366   1.0350628
19 1.118963 -0.2075476  0.114349072 1.0257646  12.3739660
20 1.142973 -0.2075476  0.080552693 1.0159785   8.5336728
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, lets see:

```
x  <-  rnorm(20,100,10)
y  <-  rnorm(20,100,10)

mod  <-  lm(y ~ x)
plot(resid(mod), y/x)  # Plot shown below
cor(resid(mod), y/x)   # about 0.67
```

[image]

so yes, there is some correlation, albeit long from a perfect one. Why is this?  If $y/x$ is large, then $y$ is larger than $x$, yes? But in that case we should expect the residual from the regression to be positive! If you look at the plot above, the relationship you can see is far from linear, it is as if all the points are above the diagonal, and this is also as expected. To see this, since $x$ and $y$ are simulated from the same distribution, independently, we expect a slope of 0 and an intercept close to the mean. Print the model object `mod` and you will see this is close!  If we use this expected values and not the estimated ones, we get the residual is basically $y-100$ which you plot against $y/x$. Got to be a relationship!

Comment: Thanks for you reply.  Maybe I need to revise my question to be more clear.  I think I already understood what you described.  But what does this mean for my application? How would I interpret the ratio as a regressor vs. the residuals as a regressor?  Do warnings about residual regressions apply to the ratio? Is there a linear model for which the residuals would equal x/y ?